# Limit and skip related column in typeorm

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to limit the related data while finding with query builder, but I miss the concept.

Here is my code to get the employee orders:

```js
import { getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";

    public async findEmployeeQuery(id : number) {
        try {
            let query = await getRepository(Employees)
            .createQueryBuilder('employee')
            .where('employee.id = :id' , {id})
            .leftJoinAndSelect('employee.customers' , 'customers')
            .getOne()
            const user = query
            return user
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }

    }
```

Now I want to limit the number of customers for each request - how can I do that?

I tried the limit and skip options but this only works with the employee, not with the joined data.

Comment: Try to do that in SQL first, to limit the numbers of relations you need to use a subquery. but it is really necessary this function ? Because this can have a considerable impact on your performance at a large scale.

Comment: You'd better make the query from the customers table not from the Employees table.

Comment: i did it for customers and it works fine Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
import { getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";

public async findEmployeeQuery(id : number) {
    try {
        let user = await getRepository(Employees)
        .createQueryBuilder('employee')
        .where('employee.id = :id' , {id})
        .leftJoinAndSelect('employee.customers' , 'customers')
        .take(4) // limits it to 4
        .skip(5) // offset 5 entities
        .getOne()

        return user
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but it will not work coz it's limit the employees and I want to limit the customers who created by this employee,, anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

You have to make another query to limit customers:

```js
import { getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";

public async findEmployeeQuery(id : number) {
    try {
        let user = await getRepository(Employees)
        .createQueryBuilder('employee')
        .where('employee.id = :id' , {id});
        .getOne()

        user.customers = await getRepository(Customers)
        .createQueryBuilder('customer')
        .where('customer.employee= :id' , {user.id});
        .limit(10) // here you set limitation you want 
        .getMany()

        return user;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i did it from the customers side and it works fine

Comment: keep this method in your mind in case you have multiple `leftjoins`, it'll help you ^^

Comment: Okay I will use it too

Comment: @Youba thanks for your help, but if user is an array, so i have to loop and it make so many query to database, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a clean way for this...

Might be of help to someone because **TypeORM does not support pagination in relations** ( let's hope that they add soon! =) )

```
 let category: any = await Category.findOne({
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
    });
    // finding products linked to that category
    let products = await orm
      .createQueryBuilder("products", "p")
      .innerJoinAndSelect("p.categories", "c", "c.id = :categoryId", {
        categoryId: id,
      })
      // implementing pagination
      .skip(offset)
      .take(limit)
      .getMany();
    // Attaching the array to the Category Object
    category.products = products;
```